# telegraf service not able to retrieve data using the journalctl commands

Tags: bash, shell, unix, telegraf

I have a shell script which executes a series of command to get some server stats. Some of these commands are using `journalctl` to get the data.

The shell script collates all the data and creates a log file.

This log file is used by the `telegraf` service to send the output to InfluxDB.

The `telegraf` service is executing as `teleraf` user. This user `telegraf` is added to `systemd-journal` group so it can execute some of the `journald` commands.

When I run the `telegraf` command `-test` flag, the first execution is not showing the output for those commands which are using `journalctl`. If I run the same `telegraf` with `-test` flag again, I see the data coming up fine.

If I leave the `telegraf` service do what its supposed to do, the output of those `journalctl` commands are coming up as empty or null.

What could be happening here?

Sample commands from shell script:

```
....

chefver=$(journalctl -u chef-client --since "35 minutes ago" | grep -om 1 -E "Client, version [^;]*" | cut -d ' ' -f3 )

osver=$(hostnamectl | grep Operating | cut -d: -f2 | xargs)

...
```

In the above code, the `chefver` is coming as empty/null but `osver` value is showing up fine.

Comment: What's the script code? Questions must provide a [mcve].

Comment: Consider asking in [UNIX & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com) with the `systemd` and `journaltctl` tags added.